# PHP Array key change

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like

```
$arr = array('key1' => 'hello');
```

Now I need to change key, is there any why I can achieve this

I know I can do this way:

```
$arr['key2'] = $arr['key1']; unset($arr['key1']);
```

But, is there any other way?

Comment: I think the copy / delete method is the best.

Comment: I don't think there is, but what's wrong with the method in your question?

Comment: @AgentConundrum: Nothing wrong in current method, but it will get worse when I need to edit lot's of keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were a little crazy you could write a function.

```
function changeKey(array $array, $oldKey, $newKey) {

     if ( ! array_key_exists($array, $oldKey)) {
         return $array;
     }

     $array[$newKey] = $array[$oldKey];
     unset($array[$oldKey]);
     return $array;
}
```

This will do nothing if the original key isn't present. It will also overwrite existing keys.

Comment: thanks alex, and please check the link that is provided by Ben, it's nice

Comment: @IMJM I've been using PHP for years and have never ran into a problem where swapping keys was the solution.

Comment: me too using PHP for 7 years, but this time I am editing someone's code, which is badly written, so had no other choice, but still thanks for the help

Comment: @IMJM Ah yeah, I know all about that :)

Answer (score 3):

The way you've done it is the correct way. You cannot modify a key in an associative array. You can only add or remove keys. If you find yourself in need of doing many "key modifications" you may need to step back and evaluate whether you're using the most appropriate data structure for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what this guy did

http://www.jbip.net/content/how-replace-keys-array-php